# Tlistbox items from database column

Tags: database, delphi, listbox, delphi-7

Is there a way to populate a `TListbox` control with items from a database column?

I know the proper way to do this is to simply use a `DBLookupListbox` control and set it up to access the column I want, but the problem with that is when I click on one of the items in the lookup control, it changes the current row in the dataset (expected behavior) but I do not want this to happen.

Instead, I would want the current row to be changed only on a double click event in the lookup control and since I do not think this behavior is possible to change, I thought it would be easier to simply use a normal `TListBox` instead, but as I stated above, I am not sure how it's done.

So once again, I have come to the experts for some advise on how to populate a normal `Tlistbox` control with items from a database column.

Comment: I removed the `binding` tag, as that has a specific meaning in Delphi XE and above (with `LiveBindings`), and your question isn't about that meaning. Also, just to make sure: you are aware that the behavior you're looking for is not standard, and is going to confuse users? The normal behavior of a list box is to click on a value to select that value; if you don't want the user to change it by doing so, disable the listbox so it can't be changed (or don't put the database in edit mode to begin with so they can't modify it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a myriad of ways to solve your problem.  You could create a hacked control of a TDbLookupListBox and override the Click method to do nothing.  You could also create a second dataset to be used for your lookup.  But as you wish, to populate a TListbox, you simply iterate the dataset and add the field value to the listbox as:

```
tLogin.first;
while not tLogin.eof do
begin
  Listbox1.Items.Add(tLogin.fieldbyname('fullname').asstring);
  tLogin.next;
end;
```

If you need a key value based on a selection, then this won't solve your problem entirely. You'd be better off hacking the TDbLookupListbox control, imo.

Comment: In the end I did something similiar, I just added another data source component to the form, tied the lookup control to that one, and disabled the orginal data source control. I then re-enable the original data source control whenever I need to see the other fields by double clicking on an item in the lookup control. Ugly, but it does the job.

Comment: Remember call the BeginUpdate, EndUpdate methods on the Listbox.Items and DisableControls , EnableControls in the TDataset.

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify DB the components which you are using, so I wrote this sample using ADO and MySQL.

```
const
StrConnection='Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=%s;Database=%s;User=%s; Password=%s;Option=3;';

procedure LoadColumn(Items:TStrings; const SqlStr :string);
Var
 AdoDataSet : TADODataSet;
begin
 AdoDataSet:=TADODataSet.Create(nil);
 try
  //you can share the connection too, in this case a new connection is made
  AdoDataSet.ConnectionString:=Format(StrConnection,['server','mydatabase','user','pass']);;
  AdoDataSet.CommandText:=SqlStr;
  AdoDataSet.Open;
  if not AdoDataSet.IsEmpty then
  begin
    Items.BeginUpdate;
    try
     Items.Clear;
     while not AdoDataSet.Eof do
     begin
       Items.Add(AdoDataSet.Fields[0].AsString);
       AdoDataSet.Next;
     end;
    finally
     Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
 finally
   AdoDataSet.Free;
 end;
end;
```

And use like so

```
   LoadColumn(ListBox1.Items, 'Select MyColumn FROM Table');
```

Comment: I am using the absolute database components and I got it working using another method. Thanks for taking the time to reply and for the example. I am sure it will be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [TDBLookupListBox](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TDBLookupListBox_Properties). Use the ListField property and ignore the DataField property.

Comment: I am already doing that and it still changes the current row when I select an item in the lookuplistbox.

Comment: You could create a second dataset for use with the lookup control.