# Tlistview - There is any component like Tlistview but with DB access?

Tags: delphi, records, dbgrid, tlistview

I've been trying to make a creative thing to avoid the `dbgrids`, and i've found the `Tlistview` (using the one from `alphaskins`, `tslistview`), and seems to be a nice way!

The problem is, I don't want to code the event `onclick` on every `tlistview` to position a `record/dataset` according to the item I selected on the `tlistview` .. and I'm doing it with the `tlistview item's caption`.. and there could be records with the same names

Here is one of the codes I want to avoid:

```
with q_find_process do
begin
  close;
  sql.Clear;
  sql.Add('Select * from t_process where process_name like '+quotedstr(streeview1.Selected.Text)+');
  open;
end;
```

And no, I don't want to put the ID of the Record on the item caption..!

Any ideas?

Does anyone know other way of showing a lot of records without being only text text and more text? I don't know all components on the tool palette, maybe someone could suggest me other one..

Comment: List view in virtual mode. You will know the position of a cursor in your dataset and fill the data to be displayed by the visible count of items (rows).

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tporpheus/  ?

Comment: also, possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551099/tlistbox-items-from-database-column

Comment: `TDBGrid` is what you need.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan .............. look what i wrote:

"I've been trying to make a creative thing to avoid the dbgrids"

"Does anyone know other way of showing a lot of records without beeing only text text and more text?"

Comment: I know what you wrote. I'm pointing out that you are rejecting what appears to be the best solution. You want a control with built in data bindings, but you won't use the controls that have built in data bindings. What we don't understand is what you have against the grid option?

Comment: You can try the [Virtual Treeview component](http://www.lischke-online.de/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview)

Comment: @RRUZ Does that have data binding?

Comment: No, but you can implement the logic to load the db data very easily. http://www.lischke-online.de/supplement/download.php?ID=60

Comment: What about LiveBindings? (duck and cover)

Comment: @RRUZ You can do that just as easily with a virtual list view.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I've used the listview in virtual mode, the performance is great, but what about implementing a custom sort clicking in a column? or adding a custom editor in a column to edit  by example a datetime? or adding a nested child row to represent a master-child relationship? all these tasks can be done much more easily in a  Virtual Treeview component.

Comment: @RRUZ That's fair enough, but bear in mind that the asker seems happy with list view, apart from the lack of data binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have sometimes used listviews which have been loaded from database tables - only for small amounts of data. I don't understand what you mean by *I don't want to code the event onclick on every tlistview to position a record/dataset according to the item I selected on the tlistview*, so I'm going to show you how I solved this problem.

Basically, I create a sub-item which holds the primary key of each record. All the user interface code uses two list views, and at the end, the database is updated. There is no interaction with the database between loading and storing (which might be where I avoid your 'onclick' problem). The widths of each fields are set in the Object Inspector; the final subitem's width is 0 (ie not displayed).

Loading the list view:

```
 srclist.items.clear;
 with qSrcList do
  begin
   close;
   params[0].asdate:= dt;  // use date of deposit
   open;
   while not eof do
    begin
     ListItem:= srclist.Items.Add;
     ListItem.Caption:= fieldbyname ('kabnum').asstring;
     ListItem.SubItems.Add (fieldbyname ('price').asstring);
     ListItem.SubItems.Add (fieldbyname ('duedate').asstring);
     ListItem.SubItems.Add (fieldbyname ('docket').asstring);
     ListItem.SubItems.Add (fieldbyname ('id').asstring);
     next
    end;
   close
  end;
```

Saving data:

```
 with dstlist do
  for index:= 1 to items.count do
   with qInsert do
    begin
     dstlist.itemindex:= index - 1;
     lvitem:= dstlist.selected;
     parambyname ('p1').asinteger:= deposit;
     parambyname ('p2').asinteger:= strtoint (lvitem.SubItems[3]);
     parambyname ('p3').asfloat:= strtofloat (lvitem.SubItems[0]);
     execsql;
    end;
```

I hope that this helps you. The context of this code (not that it matters too much) is in a financial application where the user wishes to populate a bank deposit form with cheques. SrcList holds the cheques which have yet to be deposited (there will only be a few per given date) and DstList holds the cheques which have already been connected to a given deposit form.

Comment: Well, i accepted it because the "lvitem.SubItems[3]" can be used to save the ID and be hidden (at least with the viewstyle=vsIcon), so its a nice way. I said that i didn't wanted to do the "onclick on every tlistview", because i wanted a control like the DBgrid, that when we click on a record, the dbgrid itself positions the dataset, however i'll still need to code the event on every tlistview :), but now there isn't the problem with records with the same name!

Thanks!

Comment: @FlávioGameiro: in my program, the viewstyle is vsReport. If you right click on the list view, you can define columns - both their titles and their widths. The "subitems[3]" column has a width of 0 and so is invisible.