# refresh query when changing Parameters at Runtime

Tags: database, delphi, filter, parameters, refresh

My program suppose to filter results in a listview according to the selected value in the comboboxes. Problem: listview is not being refreshed after the change of the parameter.

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //FDQuery1.ParamByName('paramA').AsString:=Combobox1.Selected.Text;
  FDQuery1.Params[0].AsString:= Combobox1.Selected.Text;
  FDQuery1.open;
end;
```

I already tried `FDQuery1.refresh` without success.

The Listview and parameter works fine at design time. The selected text also exist. No error message appears on running the program, just no refresh.

Comment: You must reload the items in listview after refresh the query,See :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589670/tlistview-there-is-any-component-like-tlistview-but-with-db-access. Or use DbGrid instead.

Comment: A DBGrid is a much better option. You can simulate a ListBox by only having one column visible without a column header. Then you get all the functionality of the underlying dataset. The other option is to write code within the OnRefresh event to load values, but it is messy.

Comment: Thanks guys, using DBGrid now and works fine

Answer (score 1):

sth like this?

```
  FDQuery1.Close;
  try
    ListBox1.Clear;
    FDQuery1.ParamByName('Param1').AsString:= Combobox1.Selected.Text;
    FDQuery1.Prepare;
    FDQuery1.Open;
    while not FDQuery1.Eof do
    begin
      ListBox1.Items.Add(FDQuery1.FieldByName('Field1').AsString);
      FDQuery1.Next;
    end;
  finally
    FDQuery1.Close;
  end;
```